# Parameter space for a class of problems

Tags: fitting, dataset

I have some simple equations like

```
p1=(9x+30y^2+28z)/Sqrt[x^2+y+z^3];
p2=(90x+30z)/Sqrt[x^2+z];
p3=(76x^2+57y+z)/z;
p4=(5x+36y)
```

Now I have the range of p1,p2,p3,p4

```
p1->{5,15}
p2->{9,30}
p3->{8,45}
p4->{16,85}
```

Now i have to find the parameter space that is the range of x,y,z

Comment: OK, so how would you do that if you were doing it with pen and paper? If you have an algorithm in mind, then we can help you implement it. You may also be interested in [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html) and [`FunctionRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange.html).

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to recognize that you are basically writing a set of inequalities, for example, that 5<=p1<=15 where p1 is the first equation. You can use Reduce to solve for the values of x, y, and z under which the inequalities hold:

```
Reduce[{5. <= (9 x + 30 y^2 + 28 z)/Sqrt[x^2 + y + z^3] <= 15, 
        9 <= (90 x + 30 z)/Sqrt[x^2 + z] <= 30, 
        8 <= (76 x^2 + 57 y + z)/z <= 45, 16 <= (5 x + 36 y) <= 85},
          {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

I added the reals because I am guessing you want to consider only real valued x, y, and z. It is not quick, but it does return a (fairly long) answer. Maybe the equations are not as simple as they might appear.

Comment: I think it is partially what i need but my requirment is that in an arbitrary x,y,z range like {1,10} which values are satisfying those inequalities and it will be totally a numerical trial and error approach of getting the required numerical values to fit those inequalities

Comment: I don't understand your comment... Reduce shows all the conditions on the x, y, and z that fulfill your four inequalities and there is no numerical trial and error. As you can see from the answer there is no simple interval range over which the inequalities hold. I suggest plotting the regions and looking at it.